# Script help - count , total and avg

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following script, trying to count how many distinct customers are there , how many distinct orders , what is total of all orders under £15 and its's avg, total of orders above £20 and it's avg.

```
with consignments as 
(select 
[Sell-to Customer No_],
[Convert-to Document No_],
ic.[Shipping Agent Service Code],
[Pick Completed DateTime] as [Shipped DateTime],
ROUND((ic.[Amount Including VAT] + ic.Postage + ic.[Gift Wrap Price] + 
ic.[Handling Fee] + ic.[Personalisation Fee]),2) as [Document Amount]   
from dbo.[Temp$Consignment] ic inner join [dbo].
[Temp$Order] oh 
on ic.[Owner Header GuID]=oh.[Order Guid]       
where ic.[Shipping Agent Service Code]='secstan' and ic.[Pick Completed 
DateTime] >= '2016-11-01T00:00:00.000' AND 
ic.[Pick Completed DateTime] <= '2016-11-30T23:59:55.000' ),summary as 
(select *,CASE WHEN [Document Amount] > 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as 'Over15' 
from consignments )select * from summary
```

I have working script like below, but as I am new to sql I am bit confused how to convert above script to below.

```
   select amountclass,[Shipping Agent Service Code],
   count(distinct [Sell-to Customer No_]) as Total_customers,
   count(*) as Total_orders,
   sum([Amount]) as total_revenue,
   avg([Amount] * 1.0) as AOV
   from
  (
  select [Sell-to Customer No_], oh.[Original Order No_], [Amount],ic.
  [Shipping Agent Service Code],
       case when [Amount] <= 20 then 'Under_20'
            else 'Over_20'
       end as amountclass
 from [TBW_BI].[dbo].[Temp$Order] oh INNER JOIN [TBW_BI].[dbo].
  [Temp$Consignment] IC
 ON IC.[Owner Header GuID]=OH.[Order Guid]
where[order date] >= '2016-09-01' AND 
    [order date] <= '2016-09-30' AND  [COUNTRY]='UNITED KINGDOM' and 
 [document type] like 'ord%' and ic.[Shipping Agent Service 
 Code]='secstan'
 ) dt

 group by amountclass,[Shipping Agent Service Code]
  order by amountclass,[Shipping Agent Service Code]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a query with a 2 Common Table Expressions (CTE) and you want to convert the CTE to a derived table. First, we can eliminate one of the CTEs.

```
summary as 
(select *,CASE WHEN [Document Amount] > 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as 'Over15' 
 from consignments )

select * from summary
```

The CTE for summary is unnecessary. We can convert that code to this:

```
select *,CASE WHEN [Document Amount] > 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as 'Over15' 
from consignments
```

Now, instead of using the consignments CTE; we can copy the sql code within it to create a derived table.

```
select *,CASE WHEN [Document Amount] > 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as 'Over15' 
from (
    select [Sell-to Customer No_],
            [Convert-to Document No_],
            ic.[Shipping Agent Service Code],
            [Pick Completed DateTime] as [Shipped DateTime],
            ROUND((ic.[Amount Including VAT] + ic.Postage + ic.[Gift Wrap Price] + 
             ic.[Handling Fee] + ic.[Personalisation Fee]),2) as [Document Amount]   
    from dbo.[Temp$Consignment] ic 
            inner join [dbo].[Temp$Order] oh on ic.[Owner Header GuID]=oh.[Order Guid]       
    where ic.[Shipping Agent Service Code]='secstan' 
            and ic.[Pick Completed 
            DateTime] >= '2016-11-01T00:00:00.000' 
            AND 
        ic.[Pick Completed DateTime] <= '2016-11-30T23:59:55.000' ) as t
```